# Show corresponding div onclick dynamic components [REACT]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm creating a riddle game. The questions are showed first with the solution in a hidden div. How can I get the target that's clicked on a specific riddle and show the solution only to that riddle inside another div.

The questions are in an object:

```
const stories = [
{ id: 1, title: first riddle, solution: this is the first solution }, 
{ id: 2, title: second riddle, solution: this is the second solution }];
```

I rendered the stories object inside Card components with mapping through all of them:

```
{ stories.map((story, index) => 
<Story key={index} id={story.id} title={story.title} desc={story.desc} grade={story.grade} /> )}
```

I tried something alongside `onClick={this.handleClick}` on the Card component, but I couldn't figure out to show the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have two `div`. First div it question, second div its solution. And only when I clicked to first div I can show second?

If I right understand case, you can manage state in your `Story` component, and when you click to first div you can set `setShowSolution(true)`

UPD:

if you use functional component:

```
const Story () => {
   ...your code
   const [showSolution, setShowSolution] = useState(false);

   const clickHandler = () => {
       ...your code
       setShowSolution(true);
   };

   return (
     ...your code

     <div onClick={clickHandler}>{question}</div>


     {showSolution && (
        <div>{solution}</div>
     )}

     ...your code
   );
}
```

or classes

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-pike-ewgoqj?file=/src/App.js:92-131)

```
class Story extends Component {
  ...your code
  state = {
    showSolution: false
  };

   clickHandler = () => {
       ...your code
       this.setState({ showSolution: true });
   };

   render() {
      return (
         ...your code

         <div onClick={this.clickHandler}>{question}</div>


         {this.state.showSolution && (
           <div>{solution}</div>
         )}

         ...your code
       );
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes correct but hence my question, how do I do that? I'm really new to REACT, I watched many video's but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: you used functional components or classes?

Comment: I have used classes

Comment: i updated example

Comment: I get an error message saying setState is undefined

Comment: my bad. sorry. `this.setState`

Comment: It works but can you also explain a little bit what is going on? I am trying to learn and not just copy paste.

Comment: no problem. so, we create variable who control us `solution` element. if variable equal `false` `Solution` element is hidden, else is visible. and when you click to the `question` you change state to the `true`. and your `solution` element can visible.


you can read about logical operators in js
link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: If I place the showSolution inside my const stories object instead of state object, how can I change the this.setState({ showSolution: true }); so it still works?

Comment: no. you cannot change in this case, because `story` object its a prop. do u can show my example code in `codesandbox`?

Comment: check example: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-pike-ewgoqj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have literally no clue whats going on in this example but ok

Answer (score 0):

```
{ stories.map((story, index) => <Story key={index} id={story.id} title={story.title} desc={story.desc} grade={story.grade} onClick={() => console.log(story.id)} /> )}
```

The OnClick Event will console the unique Identifier for each object.

Comment: This logs the id already even without clicking on the divs?

Comment: @Sbaliyev  Use this instead it will work on click the component event
onClick={() => console.log(story.id)}